# Highlighting <a> alone in bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's [navbar component](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar). **How can I highlight an `a` tag of a menu item**--but just the `a`, not the whole `li` tag?

The following is my sample HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">support</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Invoice</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"? Give it a different background color?

Comment: ya giving a different background colour

Comment: What does that question has to do with which framework was used for setup? This is basic CSS. Why is this tagged with jQuery?

Comment: @feeela: that's my "fault". suriya's original question (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14117837/1) was tagged only as 'twitter-bootstrap', I added the JS and jQuery tags because I interpreted the question to mean highlighting an element based on an event. I'll keep an eye on the q and if I'm wrong about that I'll retag...no harm meant.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the background color of **every** `<a>` in your `<li>`, in CSS you could do this:

```
.nav li > a {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

instead, with jQuery:

```
$('.nav li > a').css('background-color', '#ff0000');
```

I guess this could be a simple solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As in most things with jQuery*, there are many different ways to accomplish this. This question can be broken down into two parts:

1. how do we select only the element that we want to highlight?
2. List item how do we apply a highlight to the element?

---

### 1. Select the element

For the first part, you may want to select the element that has a certain text:

```
$(".navbar a:contains('Home')")
```

Or you may prefer to select the element by position:

```
$(".navbar a:eq(2)")
```

Let's break this selector down. The `.navbar` limits the returned objects to only the things within element(s) having the `navbar` class. The second part, `a`, further filters those objects to only the `a` elements. For the first option, [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) is a [content filter](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/content-filter-selector/). It's not one of the fastest filters, so you'll want to use it in conjunction with other selectors (in this case `$(".navbar a...`). The second option uses [the `:eq()` filter](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/). Though I'm only proposing these two selector options in this answer, see my answer to [jquery select nested div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267958/jquery-select-nested-div/14268195#14268195) for examples of other similar [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

---

### 2. Apply the highlight

Now that we have the element we want, let's apply the highlight. The most straightforward way to do so would be to just brute-force the css background-color property:

```
$(".navbar a:contains('Home')").css('background-color', 'orange');
```

An alternative that I prefer is to create a class with the intended styling (`.highlighted` for this example), and apply it using jQuery's `addClass()` method:

CSS

```
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(".navbar a:contains('Home')").addClass('highlighted');
```

---

### Go forth

See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/eMk7N/ for a working example of these concepts.

---

*-I'm using jQuery to solve this because Bootstrap is built with jQuery.

Comment: Setting background colors is achieved by using CSS. Involving JavaScript and especially jQuery is way to bloated for such a simple task. And even the Twitter Bootstrap uses plain CSS files to style the contents.

Comment: @feela: You can probably guess from my answer that I know how to use CSS to apply styling directly. My answer presumes that suriya's intent will be to highlight a specific menu item based on some event--in which case neither JavaScript or jQuery is "bloat". If I'm wrong, then suriya will happily choose an alternate answer.

Comment: But there is not a word on JS or events in the question. Your answer is nice, but it hasn't much to do with the question.

Comment: The brevity of the question leaves it open to interpretation. If I'm right about what suriya is trying to do than I like my answer.