# jquery select nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I select div that contains "my content"?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">
      <div class="">
        <div>some content</div>
        <div>my content</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

what relation does that div has with td.ms-disc-bordered-noleft?

Comment: first div has empty class, two divs that contain the actual content have no divs-- these divs are dynamically created..

Comment: Is `<div class="">` important in your tricky question?

Comment: I have no control over the markup  or i would make it more elegant..

Comment: Sarika, you have to really explain, do you need the last element , or containing exactly the text `my content`. your question is so hard to decipher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `$('.ms-disc-bordered-noleft div:last')`
- `$('.ms-disc-bordered-noleft
  div:eq(2)')`
- `$('.ms-disc-bordered-noleft').find('div:eq(2)');`
- or
  `$("div:contains('my content'):last");`

return the droid...I mean div...you are looking for.

I have a feeling that `$('.ms-disc-bordered-noleft div:last')` is your best option; [my performance test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-select-nested-div) shows that it is generally the fastest of the 4 proposals (FireFox prefers `$('.ms-disc-bordered-noleft').find('div:eq(2)');`).

See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/cfeZU for examples of the different selectors in use.

---

As for the second part of your question, that div is a 'descendant' of the `td.ms-disc-bordered-noleft` element. More specifically, it is the child of the td's child.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort! Very illustrative!

Answer (score 3):

One option as second child of inner `<div>`:

```
var div = $(".ms-disc-bordered-noleft > div > div:eq(1)");
```

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, that's always unpredictable :/

Answer (score 1):

> How do I select div that contains "my content"?

```
$('.ms-disc-bordered-noleft').find('div').contains("my content");
```

IF I did not understand well your Q. ...you can use:

```
$('.ms-disc-bordered-noleft div').find('div:last');

        ^^-parent         ^^-first children  ^^-last div
```

Comment: `$('.ms-disc-bordered-noleft').find('div').contains("my content");` would error; `.contains()` only works against a DOM element, not against a jQuery object (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/).

Answer (score 1):

It's a parent node, you can traverse up an down using `.parent()` and `.children()` or `.find()`

Answer (score 1):

Most direct route would be:

```
var div = $("div:contains('my content'):last");
```

As far as the relationship to the td goes, you could start with the above and work your way back.

```
var cell = div.closest('td');
```

These aren't necessarily the fastest options in terms of performance, but they are the shortest code. And I like short code.

Comment: `$("div:contains('my content')");` would also return that div's container.

Comment: `$("div:contains('some content')");`, for example, would return the last div and filter it for the 'some content' string...so `$("div:last");` and `$("div:last:contains('my content')");` return the same thing in this case...but `$("div:contains('my content'):last");` works to return just the desired div

Comment: Never mind. I see what you're saying. Editing now. Again. LOL

Comment: I don't know why I'm giving you such a hard time! There are 10,000 ways to do this with jQuery. I'm just enjoying testing out the different ways I don't usually try.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ms-disc-bordered-noleft div div:nth-child(2)
```

or

```
.ms-disc-bordered-noleft div div:last-child
```